# Opening show page in a modal with updating url in address bar as in instagram example using Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to achieve the attached behaviour in my Ruby on Rails 5 project.

Clicking post in index opens modal instead of linking to show page, but also updates browser's address bar with the post url.

For modal I'm using **jquery-modal** http://jquerymodal.com , 
**not using Bootstrap**

My sample codes are below ↓

[image]

---

Currently I have code below. The modal works fine but it doesn't update the url.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url.to_s), post_path(post), remote: true %>
```

**_post_modal.html.erb**

```
<div id="post-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content flex flex-wrap items-start w-100 postmodal">

      <div class="w-75-l">
        <a href="#close" rel="modal:close" title="Close"><%= image_tag @post.image_url.to_s %></a>
      </div>

      <div class="w-25-l">

        <a href="#close" rel="modal:close" title="Close" class="btn-closemodal">X</a>

        <h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
  def show

    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#post-content').html("<%= j render 'post_modal', post: @post %>");
$('#post-modal').modal('show');
```

---

and I'm getting this error at show page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line to **show.js.erb** solved the issue

```
history.replaceState({}, "<%= @post.title %>", "<%= request.original_url %>");
```

or if you don't want to change url when modal opened. Adding this line to **show.js.erb**

```
history.pushState({}, "Your Title", "<%= your_current_url %>");
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. But when I exit the modal, the url doesn't revert back. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

On ajax:success of retrieving your modal partial, you can edit the navigation bar using

```
function editURL(page, title, url) {
  window.history.pushState(page, title, url);
}
```

So something like

```
$("#get-show").on("ajax:success", function(e) {
   editURL("pagename", "pagetitle", "url")
})
```

**EDIT**

If you want your back buttons to work in browser, you must add the following code on document ready.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
   window.location.href = location.href;
});
```