# Opening show page in a modal with updating url in address bar using HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, href

I want to get id of button click in the address bar to take relivent data from database like instagram did.
I want to get id from the adress bar using php to find the specific data from database according to the id of selected reference.

**Note**
The image below is the credit of @designer from post [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596301/opening-show-page-in-a-modal-with-updating-url-in-address-bar-as-in-instagram-ex/47642442).
[image]

My code snipest is:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a    class="btn btn-primary btnModal"  data-target ="#scrapModal"  href="washingPlan.php#scrapModal?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-toggle="modal" >Service Include</a>


<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="scrapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="scrapModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">


                        <!-- DataTales Example -->
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header py-3">
                                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">WASHING PLAN SERVICES</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                
                                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />

                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>S.No.</th>
                                                <th>Washing plan Services</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>S.No.</th>
                                                <th>Washing plan Services</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>


                                        


        <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test1</th>
        <th>test2</th>
    </tr>

                                        
                                            
                                   
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form action="" method="post">

                            <div class="col-lg-8 m-4">
                                <label class="ml-1">Plans Include</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="plans" name="plans" placeholder="" class="col-12" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row m-5">
                                <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn" style="background-color: #FF9933;letter-spacing: 0.6px;border-radius: 2px;color: #FFF;">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="includeService" value="Add Value" style="background-color: #0891FF;;letter-spacing: 0.6px;border-radius: 2px;color: #FFF; display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Its address didn't not changed when I add data-target=modal. Is there any technique to make a modal like this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're looking for the [`History API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), which allows you to manipulate the browser history (including the URL bar) using JS.

[`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) allows you to 'add' a page to the history stack, which will change the URL to whatever you specify.

If you listen to the [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onpopstate) event, you can detect when the user navigates history using the browser controls (such as the back button), interrupt it and handle it yourself, all without reloading the page!

That should be plenty to get you started, it's a very useful API to take advantage of.